# Bad Request err in Node.js | The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The docu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to learn about Authentication in Node.js and I get this err while execution!

I am using express, mongoDB, passport stuff....
Trying to test SIGNUP but .... screwed up!!!

I am a beginner so cannot understand what's wrong!

This is the code:

```
//Auth part in my app.js:
//====================
  //AUTH Routes
//====================

//AUTH Routes - Show Register Form
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});

//AUTH Routes - Handle Sign Up Logic
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
  var newUser_username = new User({
    username: req.body.uname
  });
  User.register(newUser_username, req.body.pword, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render("register");
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    });
  });
});

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//This the register.ejs template:
<% include partials/header %>

  <h1>Signing Up</h1>

  <br/>

  <form class="" action="/register" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="Password">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>

<% include partials/footer %>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//And about that header.. Here is it:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>YelpCamp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">YelpCamp</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

When I hit that submit to sign up I get the BAD REQUEST err, and inside the console in the browser(Firefox) I see "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The docume...." !!

Thank you so much..

Comment: Where is the `User` coming from? I'm guessing an import somewhere?

It seems like there is something off with `var newUser_username = new User` and then calling `User.register(newUser_username,`

Comment: Yeah I have this line in the app.js;
`User= require('./models/user'),`